# CSV to ArcGIS table, insufficient text field length

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, csv

I currently use arcpy.TableToTable_conversion in order to convert a CSV file into an ArcGIS file geodatabase table. This works when string length is less than or equal to 255 characters. Whenever 255 characters is exceeded the conversion fails. Is it possible to force the textfield in the table to be larger than 255 characters?

Comment: Have you tried editing the field mapping?

Comment: Do you have a schema.ini file in the same directory as your CSV? It might be setting the field length on you. Try moving the csv or renaming the schema file.

Comment: @PolyGeo edited my question, it is a file geodatabase table but as I commented below, I Think that the solution will have to involve creating a FieldMapping object and feed that as a parameter to TableToTable_conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Chad Cooper is right. change Text Field Length in Field Mapping. Make sure your length doesn't exceed your ouput workspace (FileGeodatabase, SDE, DBF) text field length limitation

[image]

Comment: He did say he was using arcpy scripting, not the tool dialog...

Comment: Thanks, that works for manual importing. I guess I have to create a FieldMap then in arcpy and feed that FieldMap to TableToTable_conversion.

Comment: for fieldmapping check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26392/field-mapping-in-arcgis-10-arcpy or ArcPy Documentation. If you have any furthure question, start a new thread and ask your qeustion.